# How do I fix this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I was wondering if anyone could help me this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that occurs when trying to run a tester class.

The exception occurs at the remove method within the hashtable file. I have tried switching out my code with my friend's code but that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

===========================================================================

Here is the HashTable :

```
public class HashTable {

Object[] hTable;
int mSize;
int size;

HashTable() {
    mSize = 101;
    hTable = new Object[mSize];
}

HashTable(int initCap) {
    mSize = initCap;
}

Object put(Object key, Object value) {
    if (size == mSize) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No room within the hashtable");
    }

    int hashC = key.hashCode();
    int index = hashC % mSize;

    size++;

    while (index < hTable.length) {
        if (hTable[index] == null) {
            hTable[index] = new Entry(key, value);
            size++;
            return null;

        } else if (((Entry) hTable[index]).key.equals(key)) {
            Object prevVal = ((Entry) hTable[index]).val;
            hTable[index] = new Entry(key, value);
            return prevVal;

        } else if (((Entry) hTable[index]).rCheck) {
            hTable[index] = new Entry(key, value);

            while (index < hTable.length) {
                index++;
                if (hTable[index] == null) {
                    size++;
                    return null;
                } else if (((Entry) hTable[index]).key.equals(key)) {

                    Object prevVal = ((Entry) hTable[index]).val;
                    ((Entry) hTable[index]).remove();

                    return prevVal;
                }
            }
        }
        index++;
    }

    if (hTable[index] == null) {
        hTable[index] = new Entry(key, value);
        return null;

    } else {

        Object oldEntry = ((Entry) hTable[index]).val;
        hTable[index] = new Entry(key, value);
        return oldEntry;
    }

}

Object get(Object key) {
    int hashC = key.hashCode();
    int index = hashC % mSize;

    return ((Entry) hTable[index]).val;
}

Object remove(Object key) {
    int hashC = key.hashCode();
    int index = hashC % mSize;

    Object returnObj = null;

    while (hTable[index] != null) { //here is where the OutOfBounds error occurs
        if (((Entry) hTable[index]).key.equals(key)) {
            returnObj = ((Entry) hTable[index]).val;
            ((Entry) hTable[index]).remove();

            size--;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return returnObj;
}

int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String returnString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < hTable.length; i++) {
        if (hTable[i] == null || ((Entry) hTable[i]).rCheck) {
            returnString += "dummy\n";
            continue;
        }

        returnString += "Index: " + i +
                " \n Key: " + ((Integer) (((Entry) hTable[i]).key)).intValue() % 101 +
                "\nValue: " + (String) (((Entry) hTable[i]).val) +
                "\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n";
    }

    return returnString;
}

private class Entry {
    Object key;
    public boolean rCheck;
    public Object val;

    Entry() {
        key = null;
        val = null;
        rCheck = false;
    }

    Entry(Object k, Object v) {
        key = k;
        val = v;
        rCheck = false;
    }

    Object value() {
        return val;
    }

    Object key() {
        return key;
    }

    void remove() {
        rCheck = true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

Here is the hash table tester:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

public class hashTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
        HashTable hashTable = new HashTable();
        Scanner fileRead = new Scanner(new File("data1.txt"));
        while(fileRead.hasNext()) {
            Object key = fileRead.next();
            fileRead.next();
            Object value = fileRead.nextLine();
            hashTable.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(hashTable.get(key));
        }
        Scanner fileRead2 = new Scanner(new File("data2.txt"));
        while(fileRead2.hasNext()){
            Object key = fileRead2.next();
            hashTable.remove(key);
            fileRead2.nextLine();

        }
        Scanner fileRead3 = new Scanner(new File("data3.txt"));
        while(fileRead3.hasNext()){
            Object key = fileRead3.next();
            fileRead3.next();
            Object value = fileRead3.nextLine();
            hashTable.put(key, value);

        }
        Scanner fileRead4 = new Scanner(new File("data4.txt"));
        while(fileRead4.hasNext()){
            Object key = fileRead4.next();
            fileRead4.next();
            Object value = fileRead4.nextLine();
            hashTable.put(key, value);

        }
    }
}
```

===========================================================================

In the shared google drive link below you will find a zip containing data inputs.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYrzWl9mtv_io3q7K1_m2EtPFUXGbC3p/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I changed it but I'm still getting the exact same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is at this code block:

```
 while (index < hTable.length) {
    index++;
    if (hTable[index] == null)...
```

At the last iteration `index` will be the same as `hTable.length`. In your Example `index` will be 100 where the condition will be accepted. In the next step index will be incremented: `index` = 101. At `hTable[101]` the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` will occur.

Comment: Ah that fixed it, but now I have a nullPointerException occurring, thank you for your help!

Comment: May be in the cast: `(Entry) hTable[index]` ? 
Check null before you are trying to access the object.

Comment: aight fixed it only problem now is a NumberFormatException for an input string